# Why graph processing is difficult to be distributed?

Tags: graph, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

Recently I read the paper [Scalability! But at what cost?](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/hotos15/hotos15-paper-mcsherry.pdf). In this paper, authors take graph computation as an example to measure their performance on a single thread machine compared to the performance on some distributed frameworks.

In section 2, authors stated that graph computation represents one of the simplest classes of data-parallel computation that is not trivially parallelized. Can anybody tell me what are the main barriers in the parallelization of graph computing?

Answer (score 0):

The main barriers are the commutative and associative properties of the graph operations. These two properties determine if an algorithm is trivially parallelizable or not. In the page you linked the authors state the following:

> The updates are commutative and associative,
>   and consequently admit a scalable implementation [7].

Actually the cited paper at [7] is a PhD dissertation which explains it quite well:

> At the core of this dissertation’s approach is this scalable commutativity rule: In any situation where several operations commute—meaning there’s no way to distinguish their execution order using the interface—they have a implementation that is conflict-free during those operations—meaning no core writes a cache line that was read or written by another core.
>   Empirically, conflict-free operations scale, so this implementation scales. Or, more concisely, whenever interface operations commute, they can be implemented in a way that scales. This rule makes intuitive sense: when operations commute, their results(return values and
>   effect on system state) are independent of order. Hence, communication between commutative
>   operations is unnecessary, and eliminating it yields a conflict-free implementation. On modern
>   shared-memory multicores, conflict-free operations can execute entirely from per-core caches,
>   so the performance of a conflict-free implementation will scale linearly with the number of
>   cores.

For example [cartesian graph product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphCartesianProduct.html) is a commutative and associative operation, the resulting vertices can be calculated in any order, making parallelization easy in this case. However most graph operations lack either one or both of these properties.